# Date validation in CSV file

Tags: csv, awk

I need to validate DOB field in a CSV and remove the invalid data from the field.
The expected DOB format is YYYY-MM-DD only
Please see the below source file and the expected output. I'm expecting AWK command to solve this issue.

```
name,dob
pater,2022-12-10
john,1900-10-23
cader,apr 10 12056
tina,2020-maple road
mike,2019-01-35
carl,2010-03-18 new york
anne,hi how are you?
```

I need to clean the 2nd column as the DOB field. Note: in some rows, there are other text available in the DOB field and for such occurrences I need to keep only the valid date removing other text(ex: row 6)

Expected output

```
name,dob
pater,2022-12-10
john,1900-10-23
cader,
tina,
mike,
carl,2010-03-18
anne,
```

Comment: Awk is able to parse out `,` comma-delimited fields, and is able to use regexes. [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the `awk` code you have written so far, even if it is not yet working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this task by using the below command

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$2=match($2,/[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/)?substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH):"";print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

```
awk -F "," '{ if ($2 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(.*)$/) print $1 "," $2; else print $1 "," }' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Hi Thanks @Jonathan for the response, but it doesn't work 100% on the given file, it's not working on rows 6 and 7 _italic_(2019-01-35,2010-03-18 new york)_italic_

Comment: Did you check the updated version?